# Logging out/off of ELU

Tags: support, login

How do I log off this site?  I'm certain it's easy but I'm currently flummoxed!

I utilized the tags below just so I could post the query.

Comment: You could always just close your browser window, or the current tab....

Comment: Click on *Stack Exchange* in the upper left corner, *select log* out on the upper right of the resulting pull-down.

Comment: THANKS! The answer was obvious.

Comment: @Reverend: I've been here for *years*, and I didn't know/couldn't find the answer until I saw the comment from Hot Licks here. Perhaps one of you two could post it as an answer, so you can formally "accept" it.

Comment: @Hellion That doesn’t log you out. Stack Exchange is excellent at keeping you logged in, even across different devices.

Answer (score 1):

### On the desktop website

The rightmost icon in the top bar (which is a greyscale version of the Stack Exchange logo) opens a menu and "log out" is nearly directly underneath, on the same line as the name of the site you're on, next to the links for "help" and "chat".

> [image: Picture of what I just described]

If you have an unregistered account you might instead see "register". If you don't want to lose all access to your account you need to register, otherwise you can delete your cookies to log out, or use this link: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/logout. (See [How do I logout from a non-registered account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9392/323179))

### On the apps

Swipe from the left edge to the right to reveal the navigation drawer. At the bottom, under "Other", is "Log Out".